# Пунктуация в прямой речи

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

Дано 2 типа предложения.

1 тип

> 1. Я смотрел на нее и думал, как же мне ее соблазнить?
> 2. Я смотрел на нее и думал: как же мне ее соблазнить?
> 3. Я смотрел на нее и думал: "Как же мне ее соблазнить?"

2 тип

> 4. Он смотрел на нее и думал, как же мне ее соблазнить?
> 5. Он смотрел на нее и думал: как же мне ее соблазнить?
> 6. Он смотрел на нее и думал: "Как же мне ее соблазнить?"

Какой вариант правильный для типа 1 и 2?

Я всегда использую 2 вариант для первого типа и 3 вариант для второго типа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) В обоих блоках выбираем **вариант 2**

**Я смотрел на нее и думал: как же мне ее соблазнить?**

**Он смотрел на нее и думал: как же  ее соблазнить?**   Местоимение ***ему*** (а не *мне*) убираем.

**Почему подходит этот вариант**

Это прямой вопрос в БСП (подходящая грамматика), и  глагол несовершенного вида ***думал***  скорее выражает  **тему для размышления**, чем единственный вопрос (поэтому не берем вариант 3 с прямой речью, где более уместен глагол ***подумал***).

**Сравнить:** "Мы с удивлением спрашивали: неужели Сильвио не будет драться?"  Здесь также глагол несовершенного вида (со значением многократности). Но: Я спросил у них: "Неужели Сильвио не будет драться?" Здесь прямая речь, конкретный вопрос.

Думаю, что при выборе между БСП и прямой речью **надо учитывать конкретность или обобщенность вопроса.**

**Пример у Розенталя**: Спрашивается теперь (= мы можем спросить): что же делало наше общество в последние 20 — 30 лет? (Добр.);

**2) Для варианта 1** в обоих блоках: вопрос ставится как исключение, здесь меньшая выделительная способность.

3) **Вариант 3** в обоих блоках **немного меняем**. Я (он) **взглянул** на нее и **подумал**: "Как же мне ее соблазнить?" В этом случае это действительно одна мысль, а не тема.

Comment: Неясен вопрос, я же выбрала вариант с двоеточием.

Comment: Простите, имел в виду кавычки.

Comment: Да, полностью согласен!

Comment: Арина, т.е. в случае и измененным вашим 3 вариантом (Я (он) взглянул на нее и подумал: "Как же мне ее соблазнить?) всегда пишется именно так?
То есть вариант без кавычек и заглавной (Я (он) взглянул на нее и подумал: как же мне ее соблазнить?) будет ВСЕГДА неправильным?

Comment: Как автор, вы всегда имеете возможность выбора, причем возможные ограничения касаются в основном  прямой речи. Например, не слишком удачным был бы  вариант: Мы с удивлением спрашивали: "Неужели Сильвио не будет драться?".  Именно прямая речь может иногда не подойти, а у БСП  грамматика достаточно универсальная. Поэтому "Я  взглянул на нее и подумал: как же мне ее соблазнить?" можно использовать смело.

Comment: Знаете, здесь выбор похож на использование художественных средств выразительности:   дословное высказывание может быть подчеркнуто прямой речью, а может только  ненавязчиво передать информацию с помощью БСП или косвенной речи.. Составляя текст, автор обычно  чувствует  это. Поэтому при наличии вариантов речь идет не о правильности или неправильности, а о том, что лучше подходит для конкретного текста.

Comment: Конечно, рамки "правильно-неправильно" существуют, но и в этих рамках достаточно места для творческой свободы. Ваш вопрос касался в основном вариантов.  Из "неправильного" там было использование местоимения  "мне" вместо "ему" , также нежелательно ставить вопрос в косвенной речи (только как исключение)